# mockito when any value then return fixed value

Tags: mocking, mockito

Is there any of writing the below line?
Mockito.when("*.test").thenReturn("fixedval");

My expectation is a randomNumber in the place of *  like below

Mockito.when("123test").thenReturn("fixedval");
Mockito.when("787test").thenReturn("fixedval");

for any value  expecting the same return value

Comment: No. when() expects a method call on a mock, not a String. If you actually mean `when(someMock.someMethod("*test"))`, then no, it's still not correct. But it's possible to do what you want using argument matchers. They're described at point 3 of the javadoc. Why don't you read it? https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3

Comment: here I'm not expecting a method call. I'm expecting when any string value i want to return a fixed value. mock a random num+fixedString and return a fixed value. is it possible?

Comment: The  you're not understanding the principle of a mock. Which is another sign that you need to read the documentation. You want to return a fixed value **from which method of which object**? Read my comment again. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with JB Nizet's comments that reading the documentation thoroughly is essential but to give you the right direction and if I understand your question correct, you could use [Mockito's regex matcher](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#matches-java.lang.String-) for example like:

```
@Test
public void showMatches() {
    // given
    Greeter greeter = mock(Greeter.class);
    when(greeter.greet(matches(".*\\d+\\w.*"))).thenReturn("Matcher matched");

    // when && then
    assertThat(greeter.greet("none matching")).isNull();
    assertThat(greeter.greet("123matching")).isEqualTo("Matcher matched");
}
```

Now its up to you: Adapt the regex in the example to your needs and play around with it! Have fun!